# What is the Cocoa Touch equivalent to NSArrayController?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

Been starting to work with Core Data a bit, and while I've figured out how to use it in regular Cocoa applications, it seems it works a bit differently in Cocoa Touch.  How do you bind entities to objects such as table cells in Cocoa Touch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using CoreData on iPhone OS 3.0 and above, you'll want to look at `NSFetchedResultsController`. While not really an analog to `NSArrayController`, it is designed specifically to be used with `UITableView` and its controller.

It provides a way to load elements from persistence as needed, keeping in mind performance and memory constraints of the device. It's not as clean as simply binding things, but it will probably do everything you need (and more!) with a small amount of code.

Comment: Not seeing `NSFetchedResultsController`, though I do see a `UITableViewController`; are they analogous?  In any case, I'm having trouble figuring out how to feed the array data to the controller.

Thanks for the pointer about some of the environmental differences!

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` may be found here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController%5FClass/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` basically works as a helper class to `UITableView` and `UITableViewController`. It is a model class which works with your CoreData objects, and prepares them for display in a table.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, bindings are not supported in the iPhone OS. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/PortingfromCocoa/PortingfromCocoa.html) page in the Apple developer docs.

I believe this means that you can't use the NSArrayController in the iPhone OS.

Comment: you mean fortunately. ArrayControllers are awful and confuse to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Jergason is correct: you can not use bindings or the NSArrayController with Core Data on the iPhone.

Instead, check out [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which "is intended to efficiently manage the results returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a UITableView object."